# TypeScript definition for single JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, movilizer

I'm trying to run an `Ionic2` app inside a `Movilizer` HTML5 view. In order to send data between the Movilizer container client and the Ionic2 app, I need to include a `plugins/Movilizer.js` file. As I understand it, the Movilizer system will then replace that file with one that contains the actual implementation.  The contents of the file are as follows:

```
//File at: src/plugins/Movilizer.js
var Movilizer = function() {};

Movilizer.prototype.readGlobalVariable = function(varName, successCB, errorCB)
{
    result = "Hello World";
    successCB(result);
}

var movilizer = new Movilizer();
```

In order to be able to use the Movilizer interface in my TypeScript files, I believe I need to make a Movilizer.d.ts definition file. However, I'm having trouble with this. I tried the following:

```
//File at: src/plugins/Movilizer/index.d.ts
//Also tried it at: src/plugins/Movilizer.d.ts
export = Movilizer;

declare class Movilizer {
    constructor();

    readGlobalVariable(key: string, onSuccess: (value: string) => void, onError: () => void): void;
}
```

I have also tried referencing the `.d.ts` file in my `tsconfig.json` file. Adding this changed nothing:

```
//File at: tsconfig.json
(...)
"files": [
    "src/plugins/Movilizer/index.d.ts"
],
(...)
```

I tried to use the file in my FooPage as follows. This does compile:

```
//File at: src/pages/foo/foo.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import Movilizer from '../../plugins/Movilizer';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-foo',
    templateUrl: 'foo.html'
})
export class FooPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        new Movilizer().readGlobalVariable("myGlobalVariable", (result) => {
            console.log('readGlobalVariable Success: ' + result);
        }, () => {
            console.log('readGlobalVariable Failure!');
        });
    }

}
```

I'm testing the app like this:

```
$ ionic serve
```

This immediately crashes with the following error message:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./FooPage class FooPage_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__plugins_Movilizer___default.a is not a constructor
ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError
_callAndReportToErrorHandler/<
sg</d</t.prototype.invoke
NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvoke
sg</d</t.prototype.invoke
sg</v</e.prototype.run
h/<
sg</d</t.prototype.invokeTask
NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask
sg</d</t.prototype.invokeTask
sg</v</e.prototype.runTask
i
mh/</u
mh/<
Vl/r
```

**My Question**
How do I use the Movilizer.js file in my TypeScript files? If I need a `.d.ts` file, how do I create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice there is no `export` in the code of `Movilizer.js`. So, it is not a module. Then, you can't `import` it.

You could load it in the browser, not as a *module* but as a *script* (for example, not in Webpack, but with a markup `<script>`). Then it will exist as a global variable. In TypeScript, we can expect that the file `Movilizer/index.d.ts` declares the global variable. Therefore, you can just use it.

Related:

- [Here are the differences](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_browsers-scripts-versus-modules) between `modules` and `scripts`;
- Maybe it's possible to append `Movilizer.js` in the Webpack bundle, with something like the [expose loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader)?

Comment: @ABoschman: In the code of `Movilizer.js`, I can't see any `export`. Is there an `export` somewhere in this file?

Comment: @ABoschman: If there is no `export` in `Movilizer`, then you must not to `import` it. You could load it in the browser not as a module but as a `script` (for example, not in Webpack, but with a markup `<script>`). Then it will exist as a global variable. In TypeScript, we can expect that the file `Movilizer/index.d.ts` declares the global variable. So, you can just use it.